# Spurious karma error: [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an Angular 8 application with around 40 Jasmine unit tests. Now each test runs fine on its own (with the help of `fdescribe`) but when they all run together, some of the components 'appear' to throw errors, inasmuch as the report in Chrome appears with these components in the title with the following error description:

> [object ErrorEvent] thrown

I have, as I say, run each of these tests individually, and they run fine. The console isn't very helpful and reports the following:

```
zone.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:2064)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1444)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:2117)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (http.js:1195)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:126)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:116)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:102)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (scalar.js:8)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:182)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:167)
    at ____________________Elapsed_21_ms__At__Thu_Jul_18_2019_15_45_23_GMT_0100__British_Summer_Time_ ()
    at Object.onScheduleTask (zone-testing.js:107)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:400)
    at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:296)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:400)
    at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:231)
    at Zone.scheduleMacroTask (zone.js:254)
    at scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone (zone.js:1113)
    at eval (zone.js:2089)
```

Now I am quite sure none of the tests is using the `HttpClientModule` directly, instead using `HttpClientTestingModule`.

I have done as suggested in other posts and run the tests without source maps, and I have checked that there isn't any module-level code making HTTP requests. The call stack doesn't really tell me where the error in our code base is arising from. Any ideas what could be the problem?

There really is too much code to post in a StackBlitz or anything, and I can't post snippets because I have no idea from where in this largish application the error is coming from.

Comment: I had a similar issue with specs in a few of my projects. I added `afterEach(() => { fixture.destroy(); });` to all the component spec files and that seemed to help. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be thrown by an asynchronous method, you can check it by addind 'async' to your tests like:

```
it('should do something', async(() => { ... //here your test }));
```

By using this you can isolate the test that throws the error and fix it.

Comment: I excluded all of the tests with `fakeAysnc` bodies and the problem remains.